# RegEx - match specific html tags between other tag

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I´ve got a problem that I have to remove all HTML br tags in an unordered list.
The input HTML looks like this

```
<br /><ul><br /><li>one</li><br /><li>two</li><br /></ul><br />
```

Now I have to remove the br tags in the unordered list (and not the ones before and following)

I tried to solve the problem via regular expressions

```
(?<=(\<ul.*\>))(.*)(?=(<\/ul>))
```

That gives me the text between the ul tags.

But how can I get only the br tags in the selection?

https://regexr.com/5jo2s

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: E.g. using `/(?<=<ul[^>]*>.*?)<br \/>(?=.*?<\/ul>)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from Wiktor Stribizew (see above) is working

`/(?<=<ul[^>]*>.*?)<br \/>(?=.*?<\/ul>)/g`